# Docker network communication issue

Tags: windows, networking, docker

I am new to this docker, i have started running the container services in 2016 server. When i run iis image "Docker run -it -p 80:80 microsoft/iis its started successfully. but when try to access the iis sample page its not loading via local host. but i can access the docker host name and ip address of the host. I know it is limitation in WINNAT but when i try to access from my another machine using the ip address of the host ( ex. htt://192.168.1.5/ form another machine on the same n/w) iis sample page is not accessible. Can anybody help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: can you check your firewall?
tell me are you running docker on windows or linux?
did u check your container ipadresse?

Comment: i am running docker on windows and i have disabled firewall already. i have container ip so i can access but outside the host i am unable to access.  i have published to outside via 8081 port but i am unable to access